# cytoscape.js Delete Node from Memory

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

In cytoscape.js, is there a way to actually delete a node from memory completely? I wrote a layout and it consolidates nodes by making new ones and adding them to the graph, but if the layout is re-run, then I need to remove those nodes and recalculate, but there doesn't appear to be a way to allow these nodes to be garbage collected.

If there is a way to do this or is there another way I should approach this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS is a garbage collected language, so it suffices to drop all your own references to the node.  If you remove a node from a graph and don't have any of your own references to it, then the garbage collector will clean it up sooner or later.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management